# java: bound mismatch when using generics

Tags: java, generics

I am trying to implement a generic binary tree. Here's the declaration of the node class

```
public abstract class Node<E extends Comparable<E>> {
}
```

A concrete Node:

```
public class BinaryTreeNode extends Node<BinaryTreeNode> implements
        Comparable<BinaryTreeNode> {

    @Override
    public int compareTo(final BinaryTreeNode node) {
        if (this == node) {
            return 0;
        }
        return this.getValue().compareTo(node.getValue());
    }
}
```

The abstract tree class

```
public abstract class BinaryTree<T extends Node<T>> {

    /**
     * TODO.
     */
    public BinaryTree() {

    }

    /**
     * TODO.
     * 
     * @param node TODO
     */
    public abstract void addNode(final T node);

    /**
     * TODO.
     * 
     * @param node TODO
     */
    public abstract void removeNode(final T node);

}
```

This is where I get the bound mismatch, because of the T parameter of Node. I have tried having it extend Comparable, but I jut cant get it to work. How do I need to declare this? I want to make the binary tree be able to work with all classes that extend Node.

Here's a concrete tree:

```
public class ConcreteBinaryTree extends BinaryTree {

    private Node root;

    @Override
    public void addNode(Node node) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void removeNode(Node node) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

}
```

How do I need to add the type parameters here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your `BinaryTree` class needs to declare `T` as a `Comparable` too - you can use a type intersection for that:

```
public static abstract class BinaryTree<T extends Node<T> & Comparable<T>>
```

And your `ConcreteBinaryTree` class could look like this:

```
public class ConcreteBinaryTree extends BinaryTree<BinaryTreeNode> {
  @Override
  public void addNode(BinaryTreeNode node) { }
  @Override
  public void removeNode(BinaryTreeNode node) { }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply! Just out of curiosity: Is it also possible without a type intersection?

Comment: You could have two type parameters `BinaryTree<C extends Comparable<C>, N extends Node<C>>` but that would be more verbose and force the callers to always explicitly put the two type parameters when they declare a BinaryTree... I can't think of other options but there may be some.